# Is there a European equivalent of the ASMP (in particular, in Germany)?

Tags: clubs

I have difficulties to search this online without help.

In the USA there is the [Association Society of Media Photographers](https://www.asmp.org/).

I was hoping to find a similar association in Western Europe, in particular Germany (but other countries within the European Economic Area are very welcome too).

Comment: Why not contact the ASMP and ask them if they work with (or know of) a sister organization in Germany?

Comment: https://www.dgph.de/

Answer (score 2):

The [Association of Photographers (AOP)](https://www.the-aop.org/) is a trade association mainly for British & European professional photographers. They also accept members from any other country.

Answer (score 1):

Different countries, different languages, not that many EU-wide syndicates. For France try the [Syndicat National des Photographes](http://www.snp.photo/).